# How to click a button, which does not have tag name/id, on web page in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code in a web page.

```
<form class="search" target="_blank" method="get" action="Search.mvc/advanced">
    <input aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" role="textbox" autocomplete="off" class="quick ui-autocomplete-input" name="q" id="search-box" placeholder="Search" type="search">
    <button type="button" class="advanced" title="Advanced Search"><span class="icon"></span></button>
</form>
```

I want to click a button provided for search box. The web page code does not have tag name or ID.

I am using IE 8 browser.

Comment: We know almost nothing about your question. What web page? What is your current code?

Comment: Brettdj, I am automating a form filling process using VBA. So my web page is a part of a website which accepts above said inputs(form inputs), the code which I have provided is copied from view source option of the breowser which contains button code with its parent form tag. Please let me know if you need more information for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a CSS selector such as:

```
ie.Document.querySelector("button.advanced").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

(Freehand typed untested code, so might have typos. Please report back if it doesn't work)

```
Sub ClickIEButton()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim form As Variant, button As Variant

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Naviagate ("http://whateverwebsite.com")
    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set form = ie.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("form")(0) '<-- You may need to change this 0 to 1 or 2 or 3 etc....
    Set button = form.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0)  '<-- You may need to change this 0 to 1 or 2 or 3 etc....
    button.Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for quick responce. But I dont have tag name in my button HTML code "("form")(0)". How can I get it?

Comment: "form" and "button" are the names of the tag. So `...GetElementsByTagName("button")` will get all the buttons. `(0)` means that we select the first button. If the button you want to click is not the first one, then you will have to change this number accordingly. 1 for second button, 2 for third button etc.